QGIS plugin QNEAT3 iso-area polygon (by Layer) does not output Unique Point ID Field
In the QGIS plugin QNEAT3 iso-area polygon (by Layer), I have a Unique Point ID Field in my input Start Points (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 up to 10).
My iso-area distance set to 2500 m with an interval of 500m.
Therefore the output should have 50 rows (10 starting points * 5 iso-areas)
Instead the output is only 5 rows representing the 5 iso-areas. It has merged all the 500m iso-areas, all the 1000m iso-areas, etc.
If I input Unique Point ID Field, why does this not show in the output?
I cannot find any other settings to ensure this is included.
